# Is it possible to detect a collision on only a specific colour? AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, detection, bounce

I am working on a game and a border is drawn around a ball.

The border dimensions are taken from an XML file.

The edge of the border are made using:

```
    lineThick = Number(xmlContent.rec[i].look.strokethick);

    lineColor = int(xmlContent.rec[i].look.strokehex);

    drawings.graphics.lineStyle(lineThick, lineColor);

    drawings.graphics.beginFill(fillColor);
```

In a create drawings functions

Now what I want to know is how can I detect when my ball (that is moving around the screen) has hit the edge?

I thought about trying to make it detect when it hits the colour black because that is the colour of all the lines.

Is there a better way? is it possible to detect the colour black and make the ball bounce back?

Comment: Any one?! Help?! really am struggling with this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This a part of the code i use for gaming, you might have to change it slightly to your own need:
`function testCollisions():void {
     for (var i:int = enemies.length -1;i >= 0;i--) {
           tempEnemy = enemies[i]; 
          if (tempEnemy.hitTestObject(player)) { 
          //this is the part to put the code for bouncing the ball back
          }
      }
    }`

Here i am testing collision of player on tempEnemy. i have all of my tempEnemy objects in the enemies array. this might not be the most efficient but it works.

Comment: thanks for your reply.
so would this work for me considering I am drawing the shapes?
I would need to make an array for the ball is that correct?
but how would it test if it hit the drawn shapes? I'm guessing your (player) is a movie clip ?

Comment: yes. i put the player in a movieclip and used the addChild function to add it to the stage. here are two linkes to the files i use. you can use them for reference.  https://www.dropbox.com/s/oxskykggkwm91hr/Game.as https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhpgik0k3aple5w/Game.fla

Comment: you can put the drawn shape in a movie clip to allow it to be called with code.

Comment: Thanks I worked around it. But appreciate the reply!